# Cannot run Azure Function with service bus trigger

Tags: visual-studio, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I created an azure function with service bus trigger, when I try to run the function I get this error:

```
[2021-01-07T12:32:43.565Z] A host error has occurred during startup operation '4f45a03c-9302-43c6-8c54-e6555bc0f562'.
[2021-01-07T12:32:43.566Z] System.Private.Uri: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'uriString').
```

I have my local.settings.json file set up for development storage

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
    }
}
```

and I have the connection string in the function using AzureWebJobsStorage

```
public static class ProcessAS2ExchangeInboundExceptions
    {
        [FunctionName("ProcessAS2ExchangeInboundExceptions")]
        public static void Run(
            [ServiceBusTrigger("as2-exchange-inbound-topic", "exceptions", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] string myQueueItem,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");

        }

    }
```

I am not sure what the issue is. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your config, `AzureWebJobsStorage` is representing a connection string the `Azure Storage` instead of `Azure Service Bus`. So either you should define a new config to connect to `Azure Service Bus` instance with topic and subscription name (make sure to have a instance of `Azure Service Bus` is spinned-up in Azure) or use `QueueTrigger` with queue name to work with Azure Storage.

Updated below code to represent the `QueueTrigger`

```
public static class ProcessAS2ExchangeInboundExceptions
{
    [FunctionName("ProcessAS2ExchangeInboundExceptions")]
    public static void Run(
        [QueueTrigger("as2-exchange-inbound-queue", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] string myQueueItem,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");

    }

}
```

Queue Trigger - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger?tabs=csharp

Azure Service Bus Trigger - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp